# How to compute the E(x) given its cdf function?

Tags: expected-value

How could I compute the expected value E(x) given that its cdf is,

$F(x) = \dfrac{\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)}$.

I know the method to derive E(x), as in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368659/compute-the-expectation-given-cdf). I still find it very hard to derive the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to refer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf).

We have
$$F(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}\implies  f(x) = \frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{\left(e^x+1\right)^2}$$
$$E[X] = \int_{1}^{\infty}  x f(x)\,dx$$
$$I = \int  x f(x)\,dx=\frac{x \,e^x }{e^x+1}-\log \left(e^x+1\right)$$ Just use the bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it was a numerical value. Why it is not $$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  x f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Could I use a software to compute it?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx+Exp%5Bx%5D%2F%281%2BExp%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%2Cx%5D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx+Exp%5Bx%5D%2F%281%2BExp%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D

Comment: Thank you so much.